# Backbone + Firebase Collection

Tags: backbone.js, firebase

I'm building a little app and can't figure out why I'm getting an error when trying to add to a collection. Here's the code:

```
var PollCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model: Poll,
        url: 'https://***.firebaseio.com/polls',
   });

   var Poll = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title: 'title',
        }
   });

var pollCollection = new PollCollection();
pollCollection.create({title: "test"});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You had me going there for a moment, when I read `Poll` in a Firebase question. :-)    On a serious note: what error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function
message: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: However, if I move the model up above the collection everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I move the model up above the collection everything works fine